# How to change value in dataframe cell if there are two different values with the same key

Tags: python, pandas

I am writting script in Python and I am looking for optimal solution of following problem:

I have big pandas dataframe (at least 100k rows) and if there are rows with the same value in col2 but different value in col3 then I want to change all values in col3 for A

For example:

```
----------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
|   a  |   1  |   A  |
----------------------
|   b  |   2  |   A  |
----------------------
|   c  |   2  |   B  |
----------------------
|   d  |   2  |   B  |
----------------------
|   e  |   3  |   B  |
----------------------
|   f  |   3  |   B  |
----------------------
```

should look like this:

```
----------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
|   a  |   1  |   A  |
----------------------
|   b  |   2  |   A  |
----------------------
|   c  |   2  |   A  |
----------------------
|   d  |   2  |   A  |
----------------------
|   e  |   3  |   B  |
----------------------
|   f  |   3  |   B  |
----------------------
```

I solved that problem by sorting dataframe over col2 and iterating over rows, whenever value in col2 changes and in "block" of the same col2 values are different values I change col3 value but this algorithm takes around 60s for 100k rows and I am looking for more sufficient answer.

Comment: the value would be updated to 'A' everytime or there is some rule to which value you want to update ?

Comment: you can try using pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for test number of unique values and set new values by condition in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('col2')['col3'].transform('nunique') != 1, 'col3'] = 'A' 
print (df)
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     1    A
1    b     2    A
2    c     2    A
3    d     2    A
4    e     3    B
5    f     3    B
```

**Details**:

First check number of unique values per groups with `transform` for same size Series like original DataFrame:

```
print (df.groupby('col2')['col3'].transform('nunique'))
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

And thentest for not equal:

```
print (df.groupby('col2')['col3'].transform('nunique') != 1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: col3, dtype: bool
```

Last overwrite `True` rows by value `A`.

Comment: beat me to it! :D